# Hidden Input is giving null in servlet

Tags: java, forms, jsp, servlets

This question has been asked before on the forum, but I am unable to figure out from that. 
So, I am passing a form to a servlet,

```
<form method="Post" action="../JDBCConnector">
        <label for="fname">First Name : &nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">

        <label for="lname">Last Name : &nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname">

        <label for="uname">Username : &nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname">

        <label for="pswrd">Password : &nbsp;</label>
        <input type="password" name="pswrd" id="pswrd">

        <input type="hidden" name="hide" id="hide" value=1>
        <button type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submitButton">Submit &nbsp;</button>
    </form>
```

The servlet side code is,

```
String name = request.getParameter("hide");
        response.getWriter().print(name);
        String FNAME = request.getParameter("fname");
        response.getWriter().print(FNAME);
```

The output is

> null
>   TestName

Basically, I am getting a null value in the servlet for the hidden field. Can someone please tell what mistake I have made?

Comment: Use double quotes for value attribute .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML attributes without quotes are allowed only in certain conditions (obviously not allowed in XHTML, partially allowed but discouraged in HTML4.x, HTML5) , for a more detailed discussion on this [see this post](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values).

You should simply change your code in:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hide" id="hide" value="1">
```

Comment: @uranimo : Tried value="1", still returns null value in servlet.

Comment: Just to be sure that it's not something transient, have you tried to clean up and rebuild the project?

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. Once, cleaned the project and cache, it worked. Thanks a lot uranimo :)